# zpool ошибка доступа при создании раздела

Tags: freebsd

Здравствуйте!
Я использую Freenas 9.10. Поднял на нем jail, в котором необходимо установить докер (есть несколько контейнеров и переносить сервисы работающие в этихконтейнерах - не вариант). Для корректной работы работы докера требуется создать zfs раздел, который я делаю с помощью zpool.
Что я делаю:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/usr/local/dockerfs bs=1024K count=4000
# zpool create -f pool /usr/local/dockerfs
```

на последнем шаге вылетает сообщение:

```
cannot create 'pool': permission denied
```

Все команды выполняются из под рута. Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: ваш вопрос не имеет к программе *docker* вообще ни малейшего отношения. отношение он имеет к программе *zpool*, которую вы и пытаетесь выполнить. исправьте, пожалуйста, вопрос (нажав [edit]), оставив в нём только непосредственно относящуюся к вопросу информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Для создания раздела zfs надо пользоваться одноимённой командой. Например,
`# zfs create -V <size> <volume>`
Подробности в ZFS(8).